# Securing web application against information leakage

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, web-applications

What can (and can't) be done to prevent information leakage in a web application?

More specifically, assuming we've got the server, transport, and client host (desktop/tablet/phone), reasonably secured. What can be done at the client side against f.ex. a [malicious](https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/10/threat-introduced-via-browser-extensions.html) -- or [broken](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/blog/building-a-browser-extension-be-careful-not-t-17787) -- browser extension, or other threats in the browser environment as such, to prevent sensitive data leaking from the application?

Lets assume we're developing an application for storing somewhat sensitive details, which could motivate a somewhat directed, but light, attack, or at least enough to put a price on discovered exploits on the market. We're not talking launch codes to the nukes sensitive, but possibly put small company out of business sensitive.

So some sub-question to set the stage:

- Is it possible to prevent, or at least detect, a browser extension copying information from the rendered DOM and store/send it somewhere else?
- Will it help to minimize the time sensitive data stays in the DOM? That is should we try to ensure that navigation states gets thrown away and garbage collected?
- Is it better to force the user to "install" the app. (Pinned sites, add to home screen and such). How much? Can we detect the different contexts and warn the user?
- HTTPOnly and session cookie vs JWT in sessionStorage/localStorage, is it even a choice?
- What can we secure in sessionStorage or localStorage. Can we? Should we? How?

Edit:
 - If trying to secure the default browsing environment is a dead end. How could one create safe browsing environments? Private mode, can this be bookmarked? Special command line arguments to start browser with app. Can their absense be detected to display a warning? Would you do this on mobile devices too?

Answer (score 2):

> What can be done at the client side against f.ex. a malicious -- or broken -- browser extension

Very little. Browser extension code is running as part of the platform you're running on, at a higher privilege level than you. There is no recovering from a compromise at that level.

About all you can do is sniff for known bad extensions that make changes to the browser environment you can detect from page script, and refuse to run if they are present.

For example for the adware extensions mentioned you could check on-page text for unexpectedly inserted links, or enumerate `<script>` elements in the page DOM for bad `src` values. Or for some eg. Chrome extensions there may be web-accessible members you can sniff for.

But this would not be effective against:

- extensions you haven't explicitly coded for, or
- any that are subsequently updated to work around your sniffing, or
- anything coded to deliberately avoid being visible to script.

so unless you have a particular adversary in mind it is unlikely to be worth it.

> Is it possible to prevent, or at least detect, a browser extension copying information from the rendered DOM and store/send it somewhere else?

From web script, no.

> Will it help to minimize the time sensitive data stays in the DOM?

Unlikely. Anything targeting you specifically will be able to grab the data in the moment of opportunity; anything not targeting you (eg generic keyloggers) probably won't be looking in the DOM.

> Is it better to force the user to "install" the app. (Pinned sites, add to home screen and such).

It's unclear how that would help; your environment would still be compromised.

> SSLOnly session cookie vs JWT in sessionStorage/localStorage

Extension code has access to both, and can execute code inside the context of the session anyway, so no difference for this purpose.

Comment: I'm sorry i mean HTTPOnly session cooikie there.
Regarding the "install" scenario I was thinking that this creates a more isolated environment where extensions and addons aren't included. This blog from MS seems to imply that to be the case http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/11/internet-explorer-9-security-part-3-browse-more-securely-with-pinned-sites.aspx